# Getting list of Persistent Volumes with the OpenShift Java REST Client

Tags: openshift

I'm using the OpenShift Java REST Client (https://github.com/openshift/openshift-restclient-java), and I'm using some of the below code to try and do it:

```
    IClient client = new ClientBuilder(osUrl)
        .withUserName(userName)
        .withPassword(mySecretPw)
        .build();

    System.out.println("=====API & Status==================================================================");
    System.out.println(client.getOpenShiftAPIVersion() + ", " + client.getServerReadyStatus());

    IPersistentVolume volume = (IPersistentVolume)client.getResourceFactory().stub(ResourceKind.PERSISTENT_VOLUME, "DEFAULT");

    System.out.println("=====Version Etc:==================================================================");
    System.out.println("Openshift API version : " + volume.getApiVersion() +", Volume name : " + volume.getName());
```

But this is just showing information from a single volume. When I use the OC command line, via:

```
oc get pv
```

I get around 20 volumes. How can I get a list of all the volumes in my OpenShift?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    IClient client = new ClientBuilder(osUrl).withUserName(userName).withPassword(mySecretPw).build();

    List<IPersistentVolume> persistentVolumes = client.list(ResourceKind.PERSISTENT_VOLUME);
```